# HTTP POST not returning correct Response in c

Tags: php, c, http, winsock2

I have written an http client in C and created a post method to my server which is running a php script which will receive client parameters and print back some response to the client. However the server returns nothing after successful socket connection. What am i missing in my code ?

Here is my c client based of off  winsock2

```
    /*
    *   Create a TCP socket
    *   @author Salim Said
    *   Jan 7 2016
    */

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<winsock2.h>

    #pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

    int main(int argc , char *argv[])
    {
        WSADATA wsa;
        SOCKET s;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char *message , server_reply[2000];
        int recv_size;

        printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
        if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
        {
            printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Initialised.\n");

        //Create a socket
        if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            printf("Could not create socket : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        }

        printf("Socket created.\n");


    //    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("196.46.123.151");
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("66.96.147.96");
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

        //Connect to remote server
        if (connect(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
        {
            puts("connect error");
            return 1;
        }

        puts("Connected");


        //----------------------------------------------------------HTTP HEADER PLUS MESSAGE--------------------------------------//
        message = "POST /echo.php HTTP/1.0\r\n Host: www.vocha.co.tz\r\n Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n Content-Length: 16\r\n\r\n name=iAmWorking!";

        if( send(s , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
            return 1;
        }
        puts("Data Send\n");

        //Receive a reply from the server
        if((recv_size = recv(s , server_reply , 2000 , 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            puts("recv failed");
        }

        puts("Reply received\n");

        //Add a NULL terminating character to make it a proper string before printing
        server_reply[recv_size] = '\0';
        //print the Server reply
        puts(server_reply);
        //show receive success message
        puts("Data received successfully!");
        //We are done receiving data! close the socket
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 0;
    }
```

And here is my server side php script

```
    <?php

    // get name from post parameter and store it in variable $name
    $name=$_POST['name']; 

    //echo back a greeting with the user's name
    //this is what will appear in client's HTTP response
    echo 'Hi ' . $name;

    ?>
```

Here is part of the server response and my Debug messages.

```
    Initialising Winsock...
    Initialised.
    Socket created.
    Connected
    Data Send
    Reply received
    <*****Missing response is supposed to appear here*****>
    Data received successfully!
```

Comment: I suggest you print the value of `recv_size`. Also, try stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line, and check the values of all variables as you step.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for your suggestion, let me see if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message has a wrong HTTP syntax format and is rejected without response by the server.

If you take this:

```
message = "POST /echo.php HTTP/1.0\r\n Host: www.vocha.co.tz\r\n Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n Content-Length: 16\r\n\r\n name=iAmWorking!";
```

It means:

```
POST /echo.php HTTP/1.0[CR][LF]
[SP]Host: www.vocha.co.tz[CR][LF]
[SP]Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[CR][LF]
[SP]Content-Length: 16[CR][LF]
[CR][LF]
name=iAmWorking!
```

See? you've beend adding a space before the Header token ("\r\n " instead of "\r\n"), that's an invalid syntax and the server prefers silently closing the tcp/ip connection instead of taking time to respond to an attacker script (as this coudl be used by [HTTP smuggling](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-9.5) scripts).

Comment: Ohohohohoho!, removing the spaces fixed the problem, [HTTP smuggling](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-9.5) was very helpful too. Thank you very much.